# Multiple parameter passing in ajax call in MVC

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on Codeigniter. My code is:

This is my ajax method call on dropdown change event (view page)

```
$('#drp').change(function(e){  //dropdown change event
      var costcenter = $('#costcenter_id :selected').val(); //parameter 1
      var location1 = $('#location_id :selected').val(); //parameter 2
      var department = $('#department_id :selected').val(); //parameter 3
      $.ajax({
         cashe: false,
         type: 'POST',
         data:  {'costcenterid':costcenter,
'locationid':location1,'departmentid':department},
         url: 'http://local.desk.in/index.php/mycontroller/contollerfunction',
         success: function(data)
            {
               alert("success");
            }
      });
    });
```

This is my controller method (method in controller)

```
public function controllerfunction($costcenterid,$locationid,$departmentid)
    {
    echo "costcenter= ".$costcenterid;   
    echo "location= ".$locationid;  
    echo "department= ".$departmentid;  
    }
```

Getting error message:

```
Message: Missing argument 1 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction(), 
Message: Missing argument 2 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction(), 
Message: Missing argument 3 for assetcontroller::controllerfunction()
```

Why am I not able to send ajax parameter values to controller method?

Comment: show your controller method also

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Since your r posting ajax data as `post` so you have to access your data using `$this->input->post()` in your `contollerfunction` method*

Your controller method `contollerfunction` should be like this :

```
public function contollerfunction()
{
    $costcenterid = $this->input->post('costcenterid');
    $locationid = $this->input->post('locationid');
    $departmentid = $this->input->post('departmentid');

    echo "costcenter= ".$costcenterid;   
    echo "location= ".$locationid;  
    echo "department= ".$departmentid; 
    exit; 
}
```

***Note*** : See the network tab of your browser to see the output

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: if my answer helps you pls check it as green and do upvote me